# Is it possible to write Regular expression that match "nowhere" with ["no","now", "where","here"]

Tags: ruby, regex

I wonder if there are any regular expressions that match like below:

(I use ruby in the example.)

```
"nowhere".scan(/<some regex>/) #=> ["no", "now", "where", "here"]
```

Comment: What about ere,re,e?

Comment: You would need an algorithm that enumerates all possible substrings and checks whether it is in your dictionary of known words. Like `dict = %w[no now where here her]; matches = []; s = "nowhere"; (1..s.size).each do |l| s.chars.each_cons(l) do |sub| matches << sub.join if dict.include? sub.join end end; matches`. Or do it the other way round, search each word in your dictionary in the string.

Answer (score 0):

The regex to capture what you want is `/(?=(now))(no)(w(here))/`.

This will return `["now", "no", "where", "here"]` instead of `["no", "now", "where", "here"]` (the "now" and "no" are in reverse) but unfortunately this is the closest you can get. Can't have them capture in order.

If you're wondering how to match normal english words inside of other words, this is impossible with pure regex. You'd have to loop through an entire dictionary and check if there are any instances of a word inside of your test word. This is simply unfeasable.

I could be wrong, however if you're wanting to do it with regex, I would suggest otherwise. There are other ways of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions do not know what the **semantics** of a given string. So, we need to tackle the problem differently. The strategy is:

- Figure out what the possible words are
- Compare the possible words to those in a word list(english in this case)

For a word list, here is a repository https://github.com/atebits/Words/blob/master/Words/en.txt (credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3480849/630654)

```
words = File.read("en.txt").split("\n")
```

So, now we need to figure out what the possible words are:

```
str = "nowhere"
possible_words = (0..str.length).to_a.combination(2).map{|i,j| str[i...j]}
# => ["n", "no", "now", "nowh", "nowhe", "nowher", "nowhere", "o", "ow", "owh", "owhe", "owher", "owhere", "w", "wh", "whe", "wher", "where", "h", "he", "her", "here", "e", "er", "ere", "r", "re", "e"]
```

(credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3457718/630654)

Now let's filter out what possible words are actually words:

```
actual_words = possible_words.select {|w| words.include? w}
#=> ["no", "now", "nowhere", "ow", "where", "he", "her", "here", "er", "ere", "re"]
```

You can use this strategy for a variety of languages provided you have a word list for each language.

Answer (score -1):

No there isn't. Suppose such regex exists. When it matches `"no"`, the last match position is moved to the position between `"o"` and `"w"`. It is then possible to match `"w"` (and have `"no"` be a lookback), but `"no"` will not be included as part of the match.

When you use a single regex with `scan` to match against a string, **the right end of the preceding match must always precede the left end of the next match**.

Comment: Not true. You can overlap captures easily simply by using multiple captures nested inside of captures, read my answer.

Comment: @Flipybitz You are wrong. Using multiple captures will not give a flat array as a result of `scan`.

Comment: I posted my answer, which returns exactly what OP wanted. I'm not sure what you're talking about.